# Explanation for why the Moulton plane satisfies the axioms of a projective plane

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, projective-geometry, projective-space, projection

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

These series of short questions on the Moulton plane are taken from Stillwell's The Four Pillars of Geometry. Please note that text defines the Moulton plane a little differently than it is normally defined (Please see the picture for the definition used in the book).

Questions 6.1.1 was fairly straightforward, I got $x=(1,0)$, which I believe is the correct answer. Can someone confirm this? More importantly, I am having trouble making any progress with the other questions. I would really appreciate an intuitive explanations for how to approach them.

One more thing that is not clear to me from the text: is it part of the definition of the moulton plane that lines with negative gradient are unaffected  by the 'bend' that hitting the $x$ axis produces?

---

### My work:

Based on Brian's comment:

For $6.1.2$:

Suppose we have two points $A=(x_1, y_1)$ and $B=(x_2, y_2)$, where $y_2 \ge y1$.

If $y_1 \ge 0$ and $y_2 \ge 0$ OR if If $y_1 \le 0$ and $y_2 \le 0$ OR if $x_2 \le x_1$ then the points $A,B$ simply lie on the Euclidean line $y=mx +c$.

For the case where $y_2>0$, $y_1<0$ and $x_2>x_1$, to find the line connecting $A$ and $B$ we need to find $k$ and $m$ such that $y_1=mx_1 + k$ and $y_2=2mx_2 + k$

---

---

For $6.1.4$:

The points $(1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1)$ and $(1,-1)$

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct, and lines of negative slope are explicitly stated to be ordinary straight lines, so yes, they are unaffected by the bend.

Comment: how should I approach the other questions related to axioms?

Comment: For $6.1.2$ I’d simply pick points $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ and $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ and show how to determine the unique ‘line’ through them. Without loss of generality $y_0\le y_1$, but you’ll still have several cases, depending on the relationships of $y_0$ and $y_1$ to the $x$-axis and the relationship between $x_0$ and $x_1$. Similarly, for $6.1.3$ I’d simply take two ‘lines’ and show how to calculate their point of intersection. Again there will be several cases, though the case in which both are ordinary lines is trivial, as you can appeal to Euclidean geometry for those.

Comment: I managed to do 6.1.2 and 6.1.4. Please see my edit. Is my work correct for these two? I'm still very confused about 6.1.3 and 6.1.5. For 6.1.3, i'm having a hard time visualizing how the non-Euclidean cases would intersect and i'm not sure where to start. Similarly I really don't know how to start for 6.1.5. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: For Web requests: "non desarguian" or "non-desarguesian" planes.